# How about enabling "up" and "down" arrows while navigation tags suggest form

Tags: feature-request, tags

Here is a picture to make my proposal clearer. 
I can see no reason why this can be wrong, redundant, ideologically invalid or hard to implement. But I can see how this can make life a bit simpler for those who use keyboard heavily.

[image: let's get 2D!!!]

Comment: No freehand arrows...I can't approve of this.

Comment: @Bart [shabunc has an account on UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/7827/shabunc), they know how to make things look pretty over there, much better than the faux design heathens we pretend to be here with our "freehand circles".

Comment: @Bart, next time I'll use freehand ones )))

Comment: @casperOne I take back what I've said. Any user with a UX account obviously deserves my praise. Hiding my own design insecurities there...that's all that was...

Comment: @Bart While not freehand, Skitch's arrows work well

Comment: @BenBrocka, you've caught me)))

Comment: They have an extremely noticeable silhouette